# Sprite Animation system bogging down performance (VB.NET)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, performance, optimization

Ok so I have a system that is meant to run through spritesheets in order to create relatively smooth animations. It is composed of the class `SpriteAnimator` acting as the controller for the frame changes and `DeltaTimeCalculations` as a means of generating an event every frame.

The problem with it is `SpriteAnimator` needs to be instanced as it is created to host whatever image is present on an object in my game, however it still needs to receive signals from `DeltaTimeCalculations` every frame, which is a much harder task then I was anticipating.

Attempting to make an instance of `DeltaTimeCalculations` for each instance of `SpriteAnimator` results in the game grinding to a halt when more than a couple instances of `SpriteAnimator` are present due to how many individual processes are happening at once from the `DeltaTimeCalculations` instances.

I guess it is also important to lay out what `DeltaTimeCalculations` is in code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class DeltaTimeCalculations
    Private ParentObject As Object
    Private LoopTimer1 As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Private LoopTimer2 As DateTime = DateTime.Now

    Public Async Function UpdateDeltaTime() As Task
        While True
            Await Task.Delay(1)
            LoopTimer2 = DateTime.Now
            Dim DeltaTime As Decimal = (LoopTimer2.Ticks - LoopTimer1.Ticks) / 10000000
            ParentObject.DeltaTimeTick(DeltaTime)
            LoopTimer1 = LoopTimer2
        End While
    End Function

    Sub New(ReceivedParent As Object)
        ParentObject = ReceivedParent
        UpdateDeltaTime()
    End Sub
End Class
```

When an instance of `DeltaTimeCalculations` is made, the instance that created it is passed in as **ReceivedParent** which then has a subroutine, **DeltaTimeTick**, to receive the calculated **DeltaTime**.

Here is `SpriteAnimator` too but with its comments removed to reduce clutter.

```
Public Class SpriteAnimator
Public Shared MainWindowClass As MainWindow

Public VisualInstance As Image
Public VisualContainerTranslateTransform As New TranslateTransform
Public VisualInstanceTranslateTransform As New TranslateTransform
Public VisualTranslateTransformName As String
Public CurrentCropRect As Int32Rect
Public CurrentBitmap As New BitmapImage

Private Loopable As Boolean = False
Private LoopStart As Decimal = 0
Private LoopEnd As Decimal = 0
Private FrameCount As Integer = 0
Private FrameTimer As Decimal = 0
Private FrameInterval As Decimal = 0
Private FrameKeepup As Decimal = 0
Private CurrentFrameCount As Integer = 0
Private TicksEnabled As Boolean = False
Private SizeX As Decimal = 0
Private SizeY As Decimal = 0

Private CurrentSheetRows As Integer = 0
Private CurrentSheetColumns As Integer = 0
Private XIndex As Integer = 0
Private YIndex As Integer = 0

Public Shared Event TickHandleEvent()

Sub New(ReceivedMainWindowClass As MainWindow, ReceivedZIndex As Integer, ReceivedObjectName As String, ReceivedTranslateTransformName As String, ReceivedStartX As Decimal, ReceivedStartY As Decimal)
    MainWindowClass = ReceivedMainWindowClass
    VisualInstance = New Image With {
            .HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            .VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            .Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
            .StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both,
            .SnapsToDevicePixels = True,
            .RenderTransform = VisualContainerTranslateTransform,
            .Width = 0,
            .Height = 0,
            .Name = ReceivedObjectName
        }
    VisualTranslateTransformName = ReceivedTranslateTransformName
    VisualContainerTranslateTransform.X = ReceivedStartX
    VisualContainerTranslateTransform.Y = ReceivedStartY
    VisualInstanceTranslateTransform.X = 0
    VisualInstanceTranslateTransform.Y = 0

    MainWindowClass.SetGridIndex(VisualInstance, ReceivedZIndex)
    MainWindowClass.RegisterNameToGrid(VisualTranslateTransformName, VisualInstanceTranslateTransform)
    MainWindowClass.AddNewUIChildThing(VisualInstance)
End Sub
Public Sub Initiate(ReceivedRows As Integer, ReceivedColumns As Integer, ReceivedFrameCount As Integer, ReceivedSheetWidth As Decimal, ReceivedSheetHeight As Decimal, ReceivedSpriteWidth As Decimal, ReceivedSpriteHeight As Decimal, SheetUri As String, Loops As Boolean, ReceivedFrameTimer As Decimal, ReceivedZIndex As Integer)
    TicksEnabled = False
    RemoveHandler TickHandleEvent, AddressOf DeltaTimeHandler
    VisualInstance.Width = ReceivedSheetWidth
    VisualInstance.Height = ReceivedSheetHeight
    SizeX = ReceivedSpriteWidth
    SizeY = ReceivedSpriteHeight
    CurrentCropRect = New Int32Rect(0, 0, ReceivedSpriteWidth, ReceivedSpriteHeight)
    CurrentSheetRows = ReceivedRows - 1
    CurrentSheetColumns = ReceivedColumns - 1
    FrameCount = ReceivedFrameCount
    Dim NewBitmapImage As New BitmapImage
    NewBitmapImage.BeginInit()
    NewBitmapImage.UriSource = New Uri(SheetUri)
    NewBitmapImage.EndInit()
    CurrentBitmap = NewBitmapImage
    CurrentCropRect.X = 0
    CurrentCropRect.Y = 0
    Dim NewBitmap As New CroppedBitmap(CurrentBitmap, CurrentCropRect)
    VisualInstance.Source = NewBitmap
    VisualInstanceTranslateTransform.X = 0
    VisualInstanceTranslateTransform.Y = 0
    MainWindowClass.SetGridIndex(VisualInstance, ReceivedZIndex)
    If ReceivedFrameCount > 1 Then
        AddHandler TickHandleEvent, AddressOf DeltaTimeHandler
        TicksEnabled = True
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub DeltaTimeHandler()
    If TicksEnabled = True Then
        CurrentFrameCount += 1
        XIndex += 1
            If CurrentFrameCount >= FrameCount Then
                While CurrentFrameCount >= FrameCount
                    CurrentFrameCount -= FrameCount
                End While
                XIndex = CurrentFrameCount
            End If
            If XIndex > CurrentSheetColumns Then
                While XIndex > CurrentSheetColumns
                    XIndex = (XIndex - CurrentSheetColumns) - 1
                    YIndex += 1
                End While
            End If
            If YIndex > CurrentSheetRows Then
                While YIndex > CurrentSheetRows
                    YIndex = (YIndex - CurrentSheetRows) - 1
                End While
            End If
            CurrentCropRect.X = XIndex * SizeX
            CurrentCropRect.Y = YIndex * SizeY
            Dim NewBitmap As New CroppedBitmap(CurrentBitmap, CurrentCropRect)
            VisualInstance.Source = NewBitmap
    End If
End Sub

Public Shared Sub DeltaTimeTick()
    RaiseEvent TickHandleEvent()
End Sub
```

End Class

In terms of simply running through its paces, `SpriteAnimator` does what it is meant to do (with the exception of an occasional bug it has with the Int32Rect which is unrelated to this issue entirely). Functionally it works as I want it to. However, performance is significantly bogged down when more than a few instances of the class are in use and that is the problem I want to resolve here.

Seeing as making multiple instances of `DeltaTimeCalculations` was causing the game to slow down I tried a series of alternative solutions involving using only a single instance of `DeltaTimeCalculations` and instead trying to use **Shared** values in order to signal frame changes. However, since **Shared** values do not work on instances I had to find some form of workaround in order to let this data still get communicated to all instances of `SpriteAnimator`, in which I opted to use **Events**. Although it did work, the game at that point still ran too slow to look smooth let alone be playable.

I also attempted to make UI layer events get made by the Threading layer however that also yielded no better results, though I may have simply implemented it wrong as I'm not an expert on that sort of optimisation.

That is currently the state I'm at and I'm not really sure what to do as most tutorials for what I'm doing either don't give quite enough info for me to piece together a solution or are written in C# which I'm not very good at converting to VB.NET.

Any notes that may assist me with solving this issue would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `Await Task.Delay(1)` means that you are trying to run 1000 loop cycles per second. That won't work. You may need something like 50 cycles per second or so.

Comment: I would also assume that DeltaTime is always zero because you are doing an integer division. Replace that by `System.DateTime.op_Subtraction(LoopTimer2, LoopTimer1).TotalSeconds`, which is a Double value.

Comment: I do know for a fact that DeltaTime isn't zero because it has always printed values usually ranging between 0.05-0.3, with the occasional spike to something like 1.2 during small lagspikes, minus the massive bog-downs in performance I've experienced lately.

Comment: also although changing the delay did kinda help with performance, it instead resulted in a sort of extended gap between lagspikes instead of an inconsistent stream of spikes.
`System.DateTime.op_Subtraction(LoopTimer2, LoopTimer1).TotalSeconds` does help mitigate some of the issues that raising the delay causes, however performance isn't all that improved.

Comment: You may want to read [Animation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and related articles. Running a loop with one millisecond delay in an (unawaited) Task is for sure the wrong approach. Use a DispatcherTimer with an Interval not shorter than 20 ms.

Comment: I already read the Animation Overview article you linked a while back - it's pretty helpful for Storyboarding. As for the DispatcherTimer I tried implementing it and it actually has improved things somewhat. I tried setting it to tick once a second and tried hooking it up to my existing Shared event method. The result was it lagging briefly after each second passed.


Definitely an improvement but it's still not quite there since I need several frames to pass in a second and the game definitely won't be playable like that.

Comment: Why once and not 50 times a second?

Comment: You've considered conventional Wpf animations?

Comment: I set it to once a second just to see if it would lag whenever a frame changes - which it did. So I assume the problem may be in how much processing has to be done when SpriteAnimator has a tick made to it.

As for conventional WPF animations, I looked into it and I couldn't quite tell if that would work for my case as I figured that it would be better to do it frame-by-frame and thus not desync if lag happens. That being said though I'll give it another look because that might actually be the solution since the spritesheet frames are handled by moving an Int32Rect around.

Comment: If you would explain what exactly your animation is supposed to do we might perhaps be able to help you. You may perhaps also try to take a look into the different implementations of Animated-GIF libraries (e.g on GitHub) to get an idea how to cyclically update the Source property of an Image element.

Comment: I'll try to keep it brief just so I don't run out of character space: Each SpriteAnimator creates an Image object. A function called Initiate is fired to set up the instance to animate a specific spritesheet by feeding in the Uri and some other data. It adds an event handler to a Shared event for a processing subroutine during this. What it is meant to do is use a CroppedBitmap to crop the received spritesheet each time the processing subroutine is fired using a Int32Rect. It does do this, however the implementation causes it to lag severely, likely due to too much UI stuff happening at once.

Comment: Please do not write this as comment. Edit your question with a detailed description, not of what your code is currently doing, but what functionality it is supposed to implemented. What is the desired result? Perhaps write a new question.

Comment: I amended my question to state what needs changing more. Writing a new question wouldn't really be great though - especially since nothing has changed.

Comment: I looked into using Storyboard animations and that ended up not really solving my issue as there are typically at least 50+ different objects that all need animations happening simultaneously - something that storyboards can't really handle well without reduced performance.